# More than one onscroll elements by id

Tags: javascript

This code works, but i also want to change Class of one more Div, how can i do it? I know it doesnt work with getElementById(). Im new at JS so dont judge if this is something very simple.

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("header").className = "fixed";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("header").className = "";
    }
}
</script>
```

i want to add class to "logo" too

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img id="logo">
    </a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Etusivu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kauppa</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML code as well.

Comment: document.getElementById('idOfDiv').className = 'newClassName';

Comment: pass in the div id to myFunction and call it twice with ids of both the divs.

Comment: Well, what does that `div` look like? Does it have any class name? Any more information?

Comment: How come you need to set the class to fixed when you're scrolling ? Why not just keep it fixed all the time ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Catfish, there's nothing stopping you from duplicating the line that already works and changing the `id`. I don't really understand what you mean by saying you know it doesn't work with `getElementById()`.

Also, if you're not using `myFunction()` anywhere else, it makes for cleaner code to use an anonymous function, like so:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("header").className = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("logo").className = "fixed";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("header").className = "";
        document.getElementById("logo").className = "";
    }
};
```